# Preserve xts index when using rowSums on xts

Tags: r, xts, rowsum

Is there a way to preserve the index of an `xts` object when passing `rowSums` a `xts` object?

Currently I recast the result as an `xts` object, but this doesn't seem to be as fast as it could be if `rowSums` was able to simply return what it was passed.

```
xts(rowSums(abs(data)),index(data))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.  Let's ignore the `abs` calculation, as it's not relevant a lot of the time with just prices.  If your concern is performance, here is a set of timings to consider for the current suggestions:

```
library(microbenchmark)
sample.xts <- xts(order.by = as.POSIXct("2004-01-01 00:00:00") + 1:1e6, matrix(rnorm(1e6 *4), ncol = 4), dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B", "C", "D")))

# See how quickly rowSum works on just the underlying matrix of data in the timings below:
xx <- coredata(sample.xts)

microbenchmark(
    coredata(sample.xts),
    rowSums(xx),
    rowSums(sample.xts),
    rowSums(coredata(sample.xts)),
.xts(x = rowSums(sample.xts), .index(sample.xts)),
xts(rowSums(coredata(sample.xts)), index(sample.xts)),
xts(rowSums(sample.xts),index(sample.xts)), 
Reduce("+", as.list(sample.xts)), times = 100)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                                                  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#                                  coredata(sample.xts)  2.558479  2.661242  6.884048  2.817607  6.356423 104.57993   100
#                                           rowSums(xx) 10.314719 10.824184 11.872108 11.289788 12.382614  18.39334   100
#                                   rowSums(sample.xts) 10.358009 10.887609 11.814267 11.335977 12.387085  17.16193   100
#                         rowSums(coredata(sample.xts)) 12.916714 13.839761 18.968731 15.950048 17.836838 113.78552   100
#     .xts(x = rowSums(sample.xts), .index(sample.xts)) 14.402382 15.764736 20.307027 17.808984 19.072600 114.24039   100
# xts(rowSums(coredata(sample.xts)), index(sample.xts)) 20.490542 24.183286 34.251031 25.566188 27.900599 125.93967   100
#           xts(rowSums(sample.xts), index(sample.xts)) 17.436137 19.087269 25.259143 21.923877 22.805013 119.60638   100
#                      Reduce("+", as.list(sample.xts)) 21.745574 26.075326 41.696152 27.669601 30.442397 136.38650   100

y = .xts(x = rowSums(sample.xts), .index(sample.xts))
y2 = xts(rowSums(sample.xts),index(sample.xts))
all.equal(y, y2)
#[1] TRUE
```

`coredata(sample.xts)` returns the underlying numeric matrix.  I think the fastest performance you can expect is given by `rowSums(xx)` for doing the computation, which can be considered a "benchmark".  The question is then, what's the quickest way to do it in an `xts` object.  It seems 
`.xts(x = rowSums(sample.xts), .index(sample.xts))` gives decent performance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thoughtful reply Josh.

Comment: @theGreatKatzul: This is FXQuantTrader's reply. My only contribution was aligning the headers in the microbenchmark output.

Answer (score 3):

If your objection is having to pick apart and put together the components of the input then if `x` is your xts object then try this.  It returns an xts object directly:

```
Reduce("+", as.list(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My main concern was tidiness as the call already exists inside of a lapply lambda function.